# CKEDITOR.keystrokeHandler enter key behaviour

Tags: ckeditor

is it possible to bind "Enter" key to "Save page" or "Submit form" action in CKEDITOR? How to do that the best way? Thank you!

Comment: @matvey - If so, how user can type "enter" or force a line-break? Re-work your question to make it clearer?

Comment: I do not neet to make line-break - I only need the contents to be saved on enter key press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
keystrokes:
[
    [ 13, 'save'],
]
```

Comment: Where do you put that? in a plugin?